# Linked list intersection

Tags: linked-list

Would you help me with this code? I am trying to find the intersection of two linked lists. List 1 contains 42,32,54,58,96,17. List 2 contains 17,31,42,32,3,13. This is for my data structures class. I just need a hint. So far I have tried to write FOR loops. I was told to write it in a similar fashion to another loop in the assignment but it does not work. Instead of giving the intersection output which is 32,42,17 it just gives me a combination of the lists numbers.

```
 template <class Type>
void listDifference(linkedListType<Type>& difference,
                    linkedListType<Type>& list1,
                    linkedListType<Type>& list2)
{
    linkedListIterator<int> itr1;                 
    linkedListIterator<int> itr2;                 

    for (itr1 = list1.begin(); itr1 != list1.end(); ++itr1)   
    {
       // Add the each element in list 1 to the difference list
       difference.insertLast(*itr1);

       for (itr2 = list2.begin(); itr2 != list2.end(); ++itr2)
       {
          if (*itr1 == *itr2)
          {
              // If the node is in both lists delete the node from the
              // difference list.
              difference.deleteNode(*itr1);
          }
       }
    }
}




template <class Type>
void listIntersection(linkedListType<Type>& intersection,
                      linkedListType<Type>& list1,
                      linkedListType<Type>& list2)

{
   linkedListIterator<int> itr1;                 
   linkedListIterator<int> itr2; 


    for (itr1 = list1.begin(); itr1 != list1.end(); ++itr1)
    { 
        intersection.insertLast(*itr1);
            //add each element of list 1 to the insertion list

        for (itr2 = list2.begin(); itr2 != list2.end(); ++itr2)
        {
            if (*itr1!=*itr2)
            {// if node in list 1 is not the same as in list 2 delete the node
                intersection.deleteNode (*itr1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would add an element only to delete it if it shouldn't be there. You're far better off adding the element only if it *should* be there.

The pseudo-code for that would be:

```
def intersect (list A, list B):
    create empty list result
    for each elementA in list A:
        for each elementB in list B:
            if elementA == elementB:
                add elementA to list result
                break
    return result
```

Your specific problem with your C code is that, for *any* element in list B that doesn't match the current one in list A, you remove it from the intersetion:

```
if (*itr1 != *itr2) {
    intersection.deleteNode (*itr1);
}
```

So, unless *every* element in list B matches the one in list A, it will be removed. You should have some more success if you translate the above pseudo-code to your situation.

---

And, since my pseudo-code is suspiciously close to Python, we can test it:

```
def intersect (A, B):
    result = []
    for elementA in A:
        for elementB in B:
            if elementA == elementB:
                result.append (elementA)
                break
    return result

print intersect ([42,32,54,58,96,17], [17,31,42,32,3,13]);
```

and this outputs, as expected:

```
[42, 32, 17]
```

Comment: grrr! why does it say that it cannot open .exe for writing?! Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @OurFamilyPage, you're probably trying to compile the code while it's running somewhere. Stop running/debugging and the compiler will again be able to write to the executable file.

Comment: template <class Type>
void listIntersection(linkedListType<Type>& intersection,
                      linkedListType<Type>& list1,
                      linkedListType<Type>& list2)

{
   linkedListIterator<int> itr1;                 
   linkedListIterator<int> itr2; 
                
for (itr1 = list1.begin(); itr1 != list1.end(); ++itr1)
{ 
   for (itr2 = list2.begin(); itr2 !=list2.end(); ++itr2)
   {
    if (*itr1== *itr2)
intersection.insertLast (*itr1);
   }}}

Comment: That looks about right. I can't tell for sure since the formatting is not that crash hot in comment boxes, but it seems okay, nested loops (one per list) with a check-if-same-and-add in the body.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want.

```
for (itr1 = list1.begin(); itr1 != list1.end(); ++itr1)
{ 
    for (itr2 = list2.begin(); itr2 != list2.end(); ++itr2)
    {
        if (*itr1==*itr2)
        {
            intersection.insertLast(*itr1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just put this in but it didn't output. But another commenter said that it could be because for this argument every item in list 1 had to match list 2.