# Create A linkedListC out of elements common to Linked Lists A and B C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

As the name of the question suggests. I need to take 2 linked lists and create a third list out of only the elements common to the the first 2 linked lists.

here is the function I have written

```
void computeC(DLL<int> &a, DLL<int> &b, DLL<int> &c)
{
    Node<int> *hunterA, *hunterB;
    hunterA = a.getHead();
    hunterB = b.getHead();


  while ( hunterA != NULL )
    {
        while ( hunterB != NULL )
        {
            int aData = hunterA->data, bData = hunterB->data;

            if ( aData == bData )
            {
                    int temp = bData;
                c.progAppend2(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                hunterB = hunterB->next;
            }   
        }
        hunterA = hunterA->next;
    }
    c.output();
}
```

here is the progAppend2() function from my Doubly Linked List class

```
template <class Type>
void DLL<Type>::progAppend2(Type data)
{
    Node<Type> *newNode = new Node<Type>;
    newNode->data = data;

    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    else
    {
         tail->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = tail;
        tail = tail->next;
        size++;
    }
}
```

and here is main()

```
int main (void)
{   
    int a[9] = {3,7,10,15,16,9,22,17,32};
    int b[9] = {16,2,9,13,37,8,10,1,28};
    DLL<int> listA, listB, listC, listD;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    {
        listA.progAppend2(a[i]);
        listB.progAppend2(b[i]);
    }
    computeC(listA,listB,listC);
    listC.output();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am having is that for some reason ListC is not being filled with anything and just ouputs and empty list when I call output();

I think the problem is with the computeC function. The outer while loop should set hunterA pointing to an element in ListA, and the inner loop should then compare every element of listB with the element pointed to by hunterA. If a match is found then that element is copied into ListC. At leat thats how I think it should work. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked list intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919442/linked-list-intersection)

Answer (score 1):

Each time you examine a new node in A, you need to look at all nodes in B again.  For example, if the first node in A does not match any element in B (like in your input), your pointer will move to the end of B.  So, in your while loop moving through A, reset the b-pointer to the start of the b-list.

Note: it also looks like you will enter an infinite loop if the node in a and b match because you fail to break of move the b-pointer in your if-then statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think @A.E.Drew has the right suggestion for you.

I just want to add that, your solution is of time complexity O(length(A)*length(B)), a better solution is  O(length(A)+length(B)). You may hash all A-list nodes, and then iterate B-list to find if any B-node is in A-list.

Hope this also helps :)